# how do i filter google maps with checkbox and put the marker in google map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps-markers

i am having issue in filtering google map with checkbox and inserting the google map marker. here i want to filter the result through checkbox. like when i search any city in Saudi Arabia region it should show me some points respect to showroom services. showroom services filter is working as a default. now when i click on any other filter it should show the marker and when i uncheck it should remove the marker. please community help me.

here i am pasting my product link

https://cdn.assetrepository.me/maps-test/
everything is working fine except filter.
and here is the code which i am using to filter my data.

```
var listfilter = [];
$('input[name="showroom_services"]').on("change", function(){
    if ($('input[name="showroom_services"]').is(':checked')) {
        markerCluster.clearMarkers();
        listfilter = [];
        $.each(function(){
            listfilter.push($(this).attr());
        });
        $.each(jsondata, function(key, value) {
            drawMarkers(value);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/abnoor/1n4ypkju/3/

Comment: its not working because we are using private api key

Comment: for which region or city you have data? so that I can test your filter

Comment: if you want to test you can right " jeddah "

Comment: otherwise if you search any city in SA region you will find the results...

Comment: ok. I don't have too much time so I have just did some changes in your function. please check the answer

Comment: sorry where you did changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are slightly changes in this function I hope this will work. your fiddle is not working so its very hard to give the exact optimized solution. try this and I hope this will work fine. If this work fine then you will have to do some changes because this code is not optimized. your drawmarkers is calling again and again. So I will suggest that make changes in your drawmakers function and make this optimized(Probably google give some way to make the marker in more elegant way)

just replace

```
var listfilter = [];
$('input[name="showroom_services"]').on("change", function(){
    if ($('input[name="showroom_services"]').is(':checked')) {
        markerCluster.clearMarkers();
        listfilter = [];
        $.each(function(){
            listfilter.push($(this).attr());
        });
        $.each(jsondata, function(key, value) {
            drawMarkers(value);
        });
    }
});
```

with

```
    $('input[name="showroom_services"]').on("change", function(){
    var searchField = $('#showroom_search').val();
    var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    var listfilterW=[];
    markerCluster.clearMarkers();
    var markerAlreadyMade=[];
    $('input[name="showroom_services"]').each(function(){
        if($(this).prop("checked")==true) {
        let crRef=$(this);
        $.each(jsondata, function(key, value) {
            if(value['services_list'].indexOf($(crRef).val())!==-1)
                if(markerAlreadyMade.indexOf(value.dealerId)==-1){
                    if(value.city.search(expression) != -1){
                        listfilterW.push(value);
                        markerAlreadyMade.push(value.dealerId)
                    }
                }
        });
        }
    })
    $.each(listfilterW, function(key, value) {
                drawMarkers(value);
        });
});
```

I hope this will work if not then let me know. if I will be free then i will surely see this. :)

Comment: yes its working but i want to filter it services from the same city which i search

Comment: it's working but it is showing marker inside the whole region and i want the filter should work only for the city which someone search.. thanks a lot for this effort

Comment: and when i add one more service like i checked both "Showroom Sales" and "Quick Service" then the marker should appear for the both according to the city which i have searched.

Comment: actually the purpose of the filter is that to show only those services which available in searched city.

Comment: i have one idea related to it .. if we use the searched data then we will have only those coordinates which are inside the city...

Comment: i am new with json + google maps marker i don't know how its working

Comment: When You type the region or city name and you fire the api 
https://cdn.assetrepository.me/json/Petromin_en.json then you need to send the city or region name to server side and bring the filtered json only. This will make your application fast because json is very large and your application is doing too much data processing on client side that is  making your application slower. If you still want to filter the city or region on client side then check the updated code of course at your own risk. Now this will work based on filterd city but again take filtration code on server side. Enjoy :)

Comment: but i couldn't but if you will help

Comment: I have updated the code please use this. This will work for same region or city while applying the filtration

Comment: yes working with the city but it showing only one result .. for example "makkah" city has 20 showrooms but here is showing only one